# Auth driver [jwt] for guard [api] is not defined

Tags: laravel, jwt, lumen

My Application was working without any error, i am using lumen 6.3.5 and jwt 1.0.0-rc5
when i deploy the application again and make composer install, i get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Auth driver [jwt] for guard [api] is not defined. in /var/www/html/proj/vendor/illuminate/auth/AuthManager.php:97
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/proj/vendor/illuminate/auth/AuthManager.php(68): Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager->resolve('api')
#1 /var/www/html/proj/vendor/illuminate/auth/AuthManager.php(307): Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager->guard()
#2 /var/www/html/proj/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(44): Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager->__call('user', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/proj/vendor/sentry/sentry/src/State/Hub.php(98): App\Exceptions\Handler->App\Exceptions\{closure}(Object(Sentry\State\Scope))
#4 /var/www/html/proj/vendor/sentry/sentry/src/functions.php(78): Sentry\State\Hub->configureScope(Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/html/proj/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(48): Sentry\configureScope(Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/html/proj/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RegistersExceptionHandlers.php(122): App\Exce in /var/www/html/proj/vendor/illuminate/auth/AuthManager.php on line 97
```

now i cannot make any artisan command like (php artisan cache:clear, or php artisan jwt:secret)
every time i try to do anything i get the same error.
by the way the code was working 100% and i was using jwt.

this is my bootstrap/app.php:

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'throttle' => App\Http\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
]);
$app->withFacades(true, [
    Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class => 'JWTAuth',
    Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class => 'JWTFactory',
]);
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LumenServiceProvider::class);
```

and this is the auth file:

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => env('AUTH_GUARD', 'api'),
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],
```

**as i said before my code was working 100%, but after i made composer install for new deployment i get this error.**

Comment: Hello, I had the same issue I had to upload the complete project again and it worked well. seems if you run Composer Install again in local environments I make changes in multiple files s and which require a complete reupload. I tried uploading vendor folder but that didnt helped.